# Add Custom Post Type Custom Fields to WordPress Search

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I've created a custom post type for a client (gravesite), and it has several custom fields to fill out ('bcva_branch_text', 'bcva_rank', 'bcva_start_serve', 'bcva_end_serve', 'bcva_dob', 'bcva_dod', 'bcva_cemetary', 'bcva_latitude', 'bcva_longitude').

The client wants these fields to be searchable, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do it.  The WordPress Search will search the custom post type's title and 'editor' fields, but how do I get WP to search the added custom fields as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Custom Fields Search](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fields-search/) plugin looks like it will do what you need. It seems to let you choose which custom fields will be included in search.